# Replace one Byte with 3 in C# FileStream

Tags: c#, arrays, binary-data

I am going through a file and creating a CSV out of it. I have the column seperator, but not sure how to replace the one byte with three.

```
    public static FileStream stream = new FileStream(@"test.dat", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    public static FileStream shortFile = null;
    int limit = 3000;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        byte[] block = new byte[limit];
        using (FileStream fs = File.Create("tempfile.dat"))
        {
            stream.Position = 205000000;
            stream.Read(block, 0, limit);
            Console.WriteLine(Encoding.Default.GetString(block));
            File.WriteAllText("test.dat", Regex.Replace(Encoding.Default.GetString(block), "[\x00]{2,}", ""));

            for (int i = 0; i < block.Length; i++)
            {
                if (block[i] == 0x10)
                {
                    block[i] = ???;//// If I wanted to insert a "," here, how would I do that?
                }
            }
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

Comments in the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems with your code and in the end I would choose a different approach

1. `public static FileStream stream`, and `public static FileStream shortFile` - it's unusual to hold on to a `FileStream` like this and especially in a static field. I'd consider putting all streams that hold handles to unmanaged resources in a `using` block if possible.
2. You have all your code before you `MainWindow` loads (in the constructor). If this is an expensive process it will block your form from loading, also if there is an exception it's harder to handle. Also you will not be able to make this code use the async/await pattern easily.
3. You can't really insert extra elements into an array easily, you generally have to allocate a new array, copy,  insert, copy to achieve this.
4. You are seemingly dealing with bytes and strings at the same time. If you are dealing with a text file, then its better to use classes that already have Unicode in mind.
5. And I think this is the most important one. If you really want to create a csv file, save yourself a lot of time and effort and use a dedicated csv library. Read your source file, and add to your columns and rows, then save.

Comment: I come from a PHP/JavaScript background and I always forget that you can’t manipulate arrays in the same way. I know it seems like I’m dealing with whites and strings interchangeably, that’s because I have some values that are stored in hexadecimal little Endian number scheme as well as strings. Thanks for the tips

Comment: @Alan oh ok that makes a little more sense. hrmm maybe someone else can chime in with a good suggestion, good luck